# RGB to HSV wrong in colorsys?

Tags: python, rgb, hsv

I'm using the [colorsys](https://docs.python.org/2/library/colorsys.html) lib of Python:

```
import colorsys
colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(64, 208, 61)

output:(0.16666666666666666, 0, 208)
```

But this output is wrong, this is the true value using a RGB to HSV online converter:
[RGB to HSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlyu1.png)

What's going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`colorsys` takes its values in the range `0` to `1`:

> Coordinates in all of these color spaces are floating point values. In the YIQ space, the Y coordinate is between 0 and 1, but the I and Q coordinates can be positive or negative. In all other spaces, the coordinates are all between 0 and 1.

You need to divide each of the values by `255.` to get the expected output:

```
>>> colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(64/255., 208/255., 61/255.)
(0.3299319727891157, 0.7067307692307692, 0.8156862745098039)
```

Comment: What about the first value? In the online converter says 120°

Comment: Multiplying `0.3299319727891157` by `360` results in `118.77551020408164` which is close to `120`.

Comment: @DanD. After comparing with OpenCV, I think `h` should be multiplied by 180, `s` and `v` by 255: 
`green = np.uint8([[[0,255,0 ]]]); hsv = cv2.cvtColor(green, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV); array([[[ 60, 255, 255]]], dtype=uint8); then:  hsv2 = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(0, 1, 0); (180*hsv2[0], 255*hsv2[1], 255*hsv2[2]) ; (60.0, 255.0, 255)`

Comment: And for the specific example shown above: 
`colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(64/255., 208/255., 61/255.); 
 (0.3299319727891157, 0.7067307692307692, 0.8156862745098039); 
x = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(64/255., 208/255., 61/255.); 

print(x[0]*180); 
Out[194]: 59.38775510204082 ;
Then, using openCV: 
col = np.uint8([[[64, 208, 61 ]]]);
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(col, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV); 
print(hsv)
Out[197]: array([[[ 59, 180, 208]]], dtype=uint8)`